# Ways to call method local inner class from outside

Tags: java, java-8

```
public class OuterMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer outer = new Outer();
        outer.m2();
    }
}

class Outer {
    public void m1() {
        class Inner {
            void display() {
                System.out.println("msg is displayed");
            }
        }
        Inner inn = new Inner();
        //cannot write code to call display() here
    }
    
    public void m2() {
    //inner.display();
    }
}
```

Above is the code block where there is a method local inner class. The display method inside the inner class prints a message. The main class creates an instance of Outer and calls m2(). I was asked to do modification, apply any concept in java but the task is to call the Inner class' display() method from m2(). Only restriction is that the method cannot be made static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is use a private interface and make `Inner` implement it, thus enabling `m2()` to return an object with a `display()` method that can be called elsewhere in the same outer class

```
class Outer {
    public Displayable m1() {
        class Inner implements Displayable {
            @Override
            public void display() {
                System.out.println("msg is displayed");
            }
        }
        return new Inner();
    }

    private interface Displayable {
        void display();
    }

    public void m2() {
        m1().display();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three issues here

1. The type `Inner` is not visible to `m2()`
2. The instance of `Inner` created in `m1()` is not visible to `m2()`
3. The method `m1()` is never invoked.

The purpose of local classes is precisely to reduce the visibility of the class and its instances and to avoid creating the instances when the method has not been invoked. Even the initialization of `Inner` should be deferred until the method `m1()` creates the first instance of it.

A solution not perverting those properties would be

```java
class Outer {
    private Runnable accessor;

    public void m1() {
        class Inner {
            void display() {
                System.out.println("msg is displayed");
            }
        }
        Inner inn = new Inner();
        accessor = inn::display;
    }
    
    public void m2() {
        m1();
        accessor.run();
    }
}
```

Here, `m1()` doesn't invoke `display` but provides access to it using a standard interface, without giving away any information about its internals. `m2()` invokes the method `m1()` to get the access followed by invoking the standard interface method.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, we can write a class within a method and this will be a local type. Like local variables, the scope of the inner class is restricted within the method.

A method-local inner class can be instantiated only within the method where the inner class is defined. The following program shows how to use a method-local inner class

instantiate the class at proper point.
I will show you  the code*
package com;

```
    public class Outer{

    public void m1() {
        class Inner {
            
            public void display(){
                System.out.println("display from inner class");
            }
            
        }// end of inner class
       
        // Accessing the inner class
        Inner inner = new Inner();
        inner.display();            
    }//m1 ends here
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer outer=new Outer();
        outer.m1();
    }
  
   }
```

Comment: //cannot write code to call display() here

Answer (score 0):

Using reflection you can achieve this goal easily.

Here `com.problem.solution` is my package name. Replace it with your package name.

1. Get the outer and inner class object associated with the class or interface with the given string name.

   Like - `forName("com.problem.solution.Outer");`
2. Then try to access `inner class` using - `Class.forName("com.problem.solution.Outer$1Inner");`

   In java reflection, you can access any inner class using `OuterClass$1InnerClass` this type of syntax.
3. Then construct `object`, then pick your desired `method` and then `invoke` that method.

Complete code:

```
//package com.problem.solution;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class OuterMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Outer outer = new Outer();
        outer.m2();
    }
}

class Outer {

    public void m1() {

        class Inner {

            void display() {
                System.out.println("msg is displayed");
            }
        }

        Inner y = new Inner();
    }

    public void m2() {

        try {
            
            Class<?> enclosingClass = Class.forName("com.problem.solution.Outer");
            Object enclosingInstance = enclosingClass.newInstance();

            Class<?> innerClass = Class.forName("com.problem.solution.Outer$1Inner");
            Constructor<?> ctor = innerClass.getDeclaredConstructor(enclosingClass);

            Object innerInstance = ctor.newInstance(enclosingInstance);
            
            Method someMethod = innerInstance.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("display");
            
            someMethod.setAccessible(true);
            someMethod.invoke(innerInstance);
            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
msg is displayed
```

Comment: Is this solution helpful?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of interface the inner class method can be access as per your requirement :

```
    class  OusterMain{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            OuterClass oc = new OuterClass();
            oc.methodTwo();
        }
    }
    
    
    class OuterClass {
    
        public InnerInterface methodOne() {
    
            class InnerClass implements InnerInterface{
    
                @Override
                public void display() {
    
                    System.out.println("Print message.");
                }
            }
            // this reference is used to call display() method inside methodTwo()
            return new InnerClass(); 
        }
    
        private interface InnerInterface{
            void display();
        }
    
        public void methodTwo() {
            methodOne().display();
        }
    }
```